# PHP strpos return unexpected result

Tags: php

I have two strings variables and I would like to test if the first string value is present in the second tring value here is what I did :

```
$str1 = "Invoice_History";
$str2 = "uploadedFiles/Invoice_History_d22556.csv";//this is not a file it is just a string path

    var_dump(strpos($str1,$str2)); ==> bool(false)
```

the result is `false`, but the string  `"Invoice_History"` is present in the string 
`"uploadedFiles/Invoice_History_d22556.csv"` why is it giving false?
Is there a way to perform this in a working way?

Comment: How is Invoice_List present in there?

Comment: ??? `Invoice_History !== Invoice_List`. This is exactly the output you should expect.

Comment: `strpos` looks for string in string, not string in file.

Comment: Sorry my mistake It is Invoice_History I'll correct it

Comment: this is not a file it is just the string path to that file

Comment: it ain't false [here](https://eval.in/169696)

Comment: You're code is just running right, there is obviously something more that what you've shown that could make it false.

Comment: ok , working sorry thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function meant to "find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string"

if you search "Invoice_List" in "uploadedFiles/Invoice_History_d22556.csv" string, this will always be false since the substring is absent.

Answer (score 0):

`strpos()` looks for a string inside a string, not a string in a text file. You'll have to get the contents of the file to look inside of it.

```
<?php
    $listOfFiles[0] = "uploadedFiles/Invoice_History_d22556.csv";
    $file1NamePos = "Invoice_List";
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($listOfFiles[0]); // These are the actual file contents

    if ( strpos($fileContents, $file1NamePos) !== false )
    {
        // If string exists inside the file, you'll get here
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding I modified the topic

Comment: well I'm sorry it return int(14) it should be true

Comment: You should note that `strpos()` will return the position of the first character of the string you're looking for (an integer). The `true` value is usually encoded as `1` and to avoid the `1 == 14` being `false`, we use the contradictory clause (`value !== false`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1 = "Invoice_History";
$str2 = "uploadedFiles/Invoice_History_d22556.csv";//this is not a file it is just a string path

    var_dump(strpos($str2,$str1));
```

strpos is strpos(haystack, needle) so the string to look in goes first and then it's the string to find. (this returns 14)

Answer (score 0):

strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string. [1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
for example :

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
//$pos = int(0)
```

in your example the string "Invoice_List" is not part of "uploadedFiles/Invoice_History_d22556.csv" then php return false to you.

if you try with

```
$listOfFiles[0] = "uploadedFiles/Invoice_History_d22556.csv";
$file1NamePos = "Invoice";
var_dump(strpos($listOfFiles[0],$file1NamePos)); //==> int(15)
```

this is turn to you int(15).